# Making a list from the position number of another list in Racket Advanced Student

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am currently trying to write a function that gives me a list with the position numbers of the position that contains the element 1 as elements.

Unfortunately, when I execute the following function it gives me `'()`which is the initial value of `lst`.

So I am not sure what to write for the case `(< pos 0)`.

```
(define lst '()) 
(define (posj pos) (if (< pos 0)
     lst
     (begin (cond ((equal? (list-ref l pos) 1) (begin (set! lst (append (list* pos) '()))
                                                      (posj (- pos 1))))
                  (else (posj (- pos 1)))))))


(define l '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1)) 
(posj (- (length l) 1))
```

Comment: Can you show an example usage and the expected value?

Comment: If i have  '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1) as a list i want it to return me '(0 2 4 6) in which the elements are the positions who have 1 as value in '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1).

I hope it was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably meant to write was this, with `list` instead of `list*`, `lst` instead of `'()`: (and with more standard indentation)

```
(define lst '()) 
(define (posj pos)
  (if (< pos 0)
      lst
      (cond [(equal? (list-ref l pos) 1)
             (begin
               (set! lst (append (list pos) lst))
               (posj (- pos 1)))]
            [else
             (posj (- pos 1))])))
(define l '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1)) 
(posj (- (length l) 1))
```

That works, but it relies on global variables (`l` and `lst`), which isn't a very good way of doing things. Then you can translate that from global variables into function arguments. The `(set! lst (append ...))` can be replaced by passing the `(append ...)` as an argument:

```
(define (posj l lst pos)
  (if (< pos 0)
      lst
      (cond [(equal? (list-ref l pos) 1)
             (posj l (append (list pos) lst) (- pos 1))]
            [else
             (posj l lst (- pos 1))])))
(define l '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1)) 
(posj l '() (- (length l) 1))
```

So far `l` has just been the same list every time, when the part that you actually need shrinks every time. To fix that, you can iterate from front-to-back instead of back-front, and use `first` and `rest` in the recursion. Also the order of the arguments to `append` has to be switched because we're iterating in the other direction now, and the `(< pos 0)` check can be replaced by an `(empty? l)` check:

```
(define (posj l lst pos)
  (if (empty? l)
      lst
      (cond [(equal? (first l) 1)
             (posj (rest l) (append lst (list pos)) (+ pos 1))]
            [else
             (posj (rest l) lst (+ pos 1))])))
(define l '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1)) 
(posj l '() 0)
```

Now instead of using `append` it's much more efficient if you can use `cons` instead. That reverses `lst`, so rename it to `rev-lst`, and when you return it, reverse it again:

```
(define (posj l rev-lst pos)
  (if (empty? l)
      (reverse rev-lst)
      (cond [(equal? (first l) 1)
             (posj (rest l) (cons pos rev-lst) (+ pos 1))]
            [else
             (posj (rest l) rev-lst (+ pos 1))])))
(define l '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1)) 
(posj l '() 0)
```

Now it's starting to look a lot like the template for list functions, especially if you replace that `if` with a `cond`. Also, if you wanted to avoid passing `'()` and `0` as extra arguments, you could use either a helper function or a named let.

Comment: Thank you very much! ^^ 

Now i can see clearly where my mistakes are

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work (append expects only lists) and is not the way to do it in Scheme for more than one reason.

I would suggest using a [named let](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html?q=named%20let#%28part._.Named_let%29) (classic Scheme):

```
(define (posj lst val)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (pos 0) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        (reverse res)
        (loop (cdr lst)
              (add1 pos)
              (if (= (car lst) val) (cons pos res) res)))))
```

or the more "rackety"

```
(define (posj lst val)
  (reverse 
   (for/fold ((res null)) (((elt pos) (in-indexed lst)))
     (if (= elt val) (cons pos res) res))))
```

then

```
> (posj '(1 3 1 2 1 5 1) 1)
'(0 2 4 6)
```

Since you're using Racket and presumably Dr Racket (the IDE),

1. use the automatic indentation feature, it helps a lot to make your code readable
2. in order to understand how this code works, use the build-in debugger to execute it step by step
3. read a Scheme tutorial which will teach you the common looping constructs, among other useful things.

Comment: We have done Scheme at school but what confuses me are the restrictions when we change the language to Racket etc. For example some built in functions are really useful but aren't defined in Advanced Student.

And sometimes i don't get the errors that occur i search everywhere and i can't find a solution. For example i wrote a letrec inside a function and it gave me this error: "letrec: expected a variable for the binding, but found a part" because i had a function for the first variable i've tries define and lambda but nothing worked :/

Comment: Just open another question if you want an explanation. But you're right, the teaching languages sometimes have strange restrictions.